# Finding The Highest k For $k \in R$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Hello everyone how can I find the highest $k \in R$ that for him

$x + k \leq 2^x$?

Comment: Do you know how to minimize the function $f(x)=2^x-x$?

Comment: No.I tried and I got $\frac{d \cdot f(x)}{dx} = 2^x \cdot ln(2) -1 =0$. But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Wouldn't that be maximizing $k$ for the maximum $k$ satisfying $k\leq 2^x-x$?  I do not know why you speak of miniminzing, @angryavian.

Comment: @amWhy Haven't you just stated the definition of a [greatest lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum)?

Comment: The OP asks for the highest (maximum, greatest) value $k\in \mathbb R$ such that $k\leq 2^x -x$.  That's not about minimizing k, but maximizing it given the inequality, @angryavian.  Trying to minimize $2^x-x$ will not find the greatest lower bound, but the least lower bound.

Comment: @amWhy I never said anything about minimizing $k$. I am assuming the OP meant "find the largest real number $k$ such that $x+k \le 2^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$," which is the infimum of $\{2^x-x : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Someone can post a answer to my question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) = 2^x-x$ then we have

$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = + \infty \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty
$$
Moreover, as you said in the comments, if we differentiate we obtain
$$
f'(x) = 2^x \cdot \ln 2 -1 > 0 \iff 2^x > \frac{1}{\ln 2} \iff x > -\log_2(\ln 2)
$$

Hence $-\log_2(\ln 2)$ is the global minimum and

$$
\begin{split}
f( -\log_2(\ln 2)) &= 2^{ -\log_2(\ln 2)}+\log_2(\ln 2)\\
&=\frac{1}{\ln 2}+\log_2(\ln 2) \\
&=\frac{1}{\ln 2}+\frac{\ln \ln 2}{\ln 2} \\
&= \frac{1 + \ln \ln 2}{\ln 2}
\end{split}
$$
Therefore $$k =  \frac{1 + \ln \ln 2}{\ln 2}$$